# Install Ubuntu10.04 on LVM :: error: no such disk

Tags: 10.04, grub2, lvm

I installed Ubuntu10.04 on one LVM Disk.
But when I boot my computer.
It prompts:

```
error:no such disk
```

But after a few seconds,it can display the Grub menu and I can go in my Ubuntu10.04.
What is wrong?  Does anyone have the same problems?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. I went to my BIOS and disabled the floppy. It now works!